# Is this retag right?

Tags: discussion

I was answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179855/how-to-change-page-title-separator-in-dnn) which was tagged as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and few more tags.

After I answered, a user edited and removed the javascript tag itself, making my answer look dumb.

I edited again to include it.

Why was this edit approved?

Comment: The editor did not need approval. But that said, I don't directly see any justification for the particular edit.

Comment: So I was right to include javascript right? @Bart

Comment: I'd say so. I see it as a reversal of an edit that does not make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Bart, I'm now sure that I was right, since OP accepted my answer with an upvote and a comment of "thanks"!

Comment: I assume the OP is open to solutions in either c#/asp.net/javascript or jquery, hence the tags. The user that removed the tags assumed the best solution was to solve it without javascript or jquery. That user is now proven to have misjudged that. The OP could have explicitely stated that he was open for javascriot/jquery solutions but adding the tags was the first signal.

Comment: @rene I feel adding [tag:language-agnostic] makes the intention a lot clearer. Reading the question as it would be after the first edit would probably prompt people to ask which language they need the answer in. However in this case, javascript/jquery are the only languages listed, the rest are platforms. So the tag removal makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: I agree now with that @rob but I had to use a dictionary first to understand the word language-agnostic so non-native speakers might not use that tag  if they didn't run into it earlier.